# Linux - Installed Nagios but getting Forbidden 403 error

Tags: linux, fedora, nagios

I have installed nagios successfully on fedora 17. but when I am trying to connect to nagios like http://mylocalhost.com/nagios. It asks for username and password. After putting these information I am found out **forbidden 403 error** with message , You dont have permission to access /nagios/ on this server.

I am bit confused how to resolve this issue. I read some post. they were saying to create empty index.html inside http root directory. i tried but same error is there.

http://www.unixmen.com/nagios-http-warning-http11-403-forbidden-solved/

If I am not wrong http root directory is /var/www/html?

Comment: What's your Apache configuration (a virtualhost may have been created for Nagios)?

Comment: default configuration sir. I havnt touch defualt configuration. only single change is about Keepalive variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops ... sorry it was problem with my **httpd service** which was running actually but not accessible for publicly.

simply I flushed out iptables. then Checked out httpd service whether it is running properly or not.

Now its working great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you create file index.html in /var/www/html.
After you can restart service nagios and httpd